# how to make a shape like the picture below using a shape drawable?

Tags: android, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I met a difficulty in Android programming, I want to make a shape like the picture "[supposed.bmp](http://www.yiuliu.cn/tempshare/supposed.bmp)" I uploaded. But I don't know how to do that, I only made one like "[actual.bmp](http://www.yiuliu.cn/tempshare/actual.bmp)" I uploaded by the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"/>

    <solid
        android:color="#199900"/>

    <size
        android:height="20dp"
        android:width="20dp"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#004A00"/>
</shape>
```

please help me to correct the code above, thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded the correct images I just see white squares in both images?

Comment: Oh I found that maybe it was a server problem and I uploaded new pics just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this may help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="#ffffff"/>

            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp"/>

            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#004A00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:bottom="30dp"
        android:left="30dp"
        android:top="30dp"
        android:right="30dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="#004A00"/>

            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**Edited:**

You may avoid the `size` attribute.

Increase or decrease `top`, `bottom`, `right`, `left` value to make the inner circle smaller or larger.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really solved my problem. And one more problem occurred. When it comes to newer version of Android, when we press the radiobutton a pink shadow will appear. It will be strange if I use green radiobutton with pink shadow. I rather want to know how to remove the shadow.

Comment: If the answer helped you to solve your problem then please accept the answer first to help other people who might be face this problem in future. :) For your next problem I have to check it first. :)

Comment: It didn't work if I use Selector, maybe you misunderstood my meanings.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#199900" />
        <size android:width="15dp" android:height="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke  android:width="6dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <solid android:color="#199900" />
        <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#0c720c"/>
        <size
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="100dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="12dp"
            android:color="@color/transparent"/>
        <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="50dp"
            android:color="@color/transparent"/>
        <solid android:color="#0c720c"/>
    </shape>
</item>


</layer-list>
```